# call another ajax function recursively from ajax success

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a web page that is used to request the reports. When the user clicks a button, I am calling a function that will make a ajax request to process the reports. Once the request is made, I am using setInterval function to check the status of the report (whether is completed or not) every 1 second. Some how, the function inside setInterval() is not called at all.

Following is the javascript code that I have

```
var GLFiles_JSObject = {
        url: "<%= Request.ApplicationPath %>/AjaxRequest.aspx",
        apppath: '<%= Request.ApplicationPath %>',
        btnRefreshId: '<%= btnRefresh.ClientID %>',
        ajaxFunctionName: 'GLBuilder_ReprocessFiles', 
        reportstatusFuncName: 'GLBuilder_GetReportStatus', 
        reportid: 0,
        ajaxError: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){ 
            alert(XMLHttpRequest.statusText);        
        },
        ajaxSuccess: function(msg) {                
            if (msg === '') {
                setInterval(function(){
                    this.reportstatus();                    
                }, 1000);                        
            }                
        },
        reportstatusSuccess : function(msg) {                
            if (msg === '1') {
                clearInterval();
            }
        },
        reportstatus : function() {
            var keys = new Array('reportid');
            var values = new Array(reportid);
            //ajax call
            WebServicePost(true, this.url, this.reportstatusFuncName, keys, values, this.ajaxError, this.reportstatusSuccess);                                                                                  
        }            
    };            

    //this will be called when button is clicked.
    function reprocessGLFiles(reportid, btnid) {            
        //disable the button
        //$('#' + btnid).attr("disabled", true);
        GLFiles_JSObject.reportid = reportid;

        var keys = new Array('reportid');
        var values = new Array(GLFiles_JSObject.reportid);
       // make an ajax request to process the files
        WebServicePost(true, GLFiles_JSObject.url, GLFiles_JSObject.ajaxFunctionName, keys, values, GLFiles_JSObject.ajaxError, GLFiles_JSObject.ajaxSuccess);                                                     

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is not being called is probably because you using the `this` var which means something else. If you change `this.reportstatus();` to `GLFiles_JSObject.reportstatus()` will probably fix your problem.

On a different note, I think you are misunderstanding something here. Why do you need to call a timer method for this to check status. OnSuccess is called when the method the ajax request is finished. So you don't need to call setTimeout.

Comment: when I request the report, the system will just update the status to waiting. Then there is a windows service that picks up the waiting records and processes the reports. so, I want to query the database to check if the reports are processed. And when they are processed, I will refresh the page with new reports.